# Poly1305 command line in OpenSSL

Tags: hash, openssl, digest-authentication

I am trying to execute basic ChaCha20-Poly1305 cipher suite using OpenSSL without any TLS or any Apache server. I have succesfully encrypted my text with Chacha20 openssl command but I am unable to produce Poly1305 MAC authentication. I am using dgst command and it seems it only generates SHA algorithm. I am using 1.1.1 openssl version. Can somebody tell me which command shall I use?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a file F you can compute the Poly1305 with the following command:

```
openssl dgst -mac poly1305 -macopt key:abcd1234abcd1234abcd1234abcd1234 <PATH_TO_F>
```

The key may also be a hex value with 32 bytes:

```
openssl dgst -mac poly1305 -macopt hexkey:ee00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffffffffffffff <PATH_TO_F>
```